# React.js map function doesn't display value with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using the new hooks API. I have this piece of code for state:

```
const [feedbackArray, setFeedbackArray] = useState<Feedback[]>([]);
```

Next I update the value of this array with the following function

```
const submitWord = (word: string) => {
    if (word.length === wordLength) {
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT + "/rounds", {method: "POST", body: word})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((feedback: Feedback) => {
                if (feedbackArray) {
                    setFeedbackArray([...feedbackArray, feedback])
                }
            })
    }
}
```

I call the function with a button

```
<Button onClick={() => submitWord(word)}>Submit word</Button>
```

Next I want to display the display the values in some elements

```
return (<div>
<!--some code-->
{
    feedbackArray.map((feedback: Feedback) => {
        return (<div>
            <p>{feedback.letter}</p>
            <TextField value={feedback.letter}/>
            <TextField value={feedback.status}/>
        </div>)
    })}
</div>)
```

But the values in feedback.letter are empty. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to use the useEffect hook? How do I have to use it then?

Comment: Have you validated you are getting back a response with a `feedback` value and your state is actually updated? `fetch` requests will still resolve for server errors so you will likely want to check the `response.ok` property. Is the state really populated?

Comment: I can see in a `console.log` above the `return` line that there is a `Feedback` object. Inside the `return` the value is `undefined`

Comment: And what is logged when you `console.log(feedback);` int he map callback?

Comment: the actual values of the feedback object

Comment: Well, if `feedback.letter` and etcetera are defined when you log them in the map callback they should still be defined a line or two later when rendering them to JSX. In case it's unclear, you *are* referring to logging `feedback` above the `return` in the map callback, yes? or are you referring to the function's return  above that?

Comment: you would think so yes

Comment: If you've got a `feedback` object in state that you can target, but it's blank, then the issue is almost certainly on the server-side (i.e. you are returning either a fully or partially blank object).

Comment: "you would think so..." Have you *confirmed* the properties `letter` & `status` exist on the `feedback` object, and are truthy, when you log it in the callback?